# Justifiable reason to use a Submachine Gun in the post-apocalypse?

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons, post-apocalypse

In my world, I planned on the use of **SMGs** (Submachine Guns) being common, with weapons like the H&K MP9, MAC-27, and UZI being most common. After doing some thinking though, I realized that in such a world, where pretty much every bullet counted, I’d need a real reason to justify SMGs being used by Wastelanders.

**In what situations while traveling a post-nuclear wasteland could an SMG prove useful?**

**Background Info**

- The world is one in which threats like giant mutant wildlife, human raiders, and mutant warriors are common threats.
- Average wastelanders usually carry rifles, pistols, or shotguns.
- Amount of ammo is a really big concern, as it either has to be scavenged or traded for, so they’d need a good reason to use a burst-firing weapon.

Comment: How is this about building a fictional world? This looks like a question that is highly dependent upon the circumstances and nature of the individual involved.

Comment: There's no way to judge which answer is better, "they're the only guns anyone can find" or "they're too useful against the crowds of radioactive mutants." Without explaining how you will judge a best answer, the question is either situational (story-based) or opinion-based. Per the [help/dont-ask], "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid."

Comment: All these answers talk about ammo availability but the bigger problem is that there are no replacement gun barrels or other moving parts being manufactured in the post-apocalyptic world.  When the SMG barrels wear out, it won't matter how many bullets are lying around, everybody's going back to crudely made single-shot zip guns.

Comment: A world where H&K MP9 is more popular than the AK-47 is unbelievable from the start.

Comment: @AlexP: It’s America. They’re all using AR-15s.

Comment: @JBH: can we at least...talk about post apocalyptic weapons in a chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pre-apocalyptic surplus

> the use of SMGs (Submachine Guns) being common

Common does not equal ubiquitous. SMG's could be to your world, during pre-apocalypse times, what the AK-47 is to ours - manufactured to no end.

Sure, new ammunition is not being produced anymore. But you can find a cache here and there, with bullets that will last you maybe a couple fights. Finding these would be like finding a temporary power up in a game. And if you have it, why not use it?

It may be that 10 years from the (current, post apocalyptic) time there really won't be any ammo left so SMG's will really be a thing from the past. But for now, just because they are not infinite does not mean you have to send whatever you find to a museum.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to build on the other answers - some ammo (like 9×19mm Parabellum) would be extremely abundant, while other (like 5.56×45mm NATO or 7.62×39mm) are very rare.

Abundance of pistol cartridges would make submachine guns a very powerful weapons while more serious rifles like M4 or AK-47 would not see much use.

Shortage of ammunition can be easily explained in post-apocalypse. Abundance of ammunition is harder to explain. Here are the options:

1. Pre-apocalypse stockpile. There was a very large ammunition depot in the area which stocked only particular types of ammo. During the apocalypse, the depot was pillaged, and ammo preserved by various groups which later traded it with each other as well as with individuals;
2. Operational factory. After the apocalypse, a full technological process for manufacturing of ammo was restored - but only for one particular cartridge type. The factory is kept operational, but expanding its production to some other variety of ammo is for some reason not possible.

Answer (score 1):

### Fire discipline is a future concern and not all ammo is equal

You have to survive the now in order to participate in the future. As long as using SMG's now increases the odds of surviving the present (or even just thought to do so), they will be used.

Mac-10 is a good example, it can be chambered for 9mm or 45-ACP. Both of these are rounds commonly used with handguns. So arguably, using a Mac-10 will constrain your future supply of handgun ammo.

But, suppose you have a lot of 22 Long Rifle ammo - the most popular popular ammo round. It is unlikely (though not impossible) that you will have an SMG that can fire 22 LR. In which case, using your SMGs will not affect the longer term availability of your rifle defense. 22 LR is also reasonably common for hand-guns.

Uzis can be fitted with for use of 22 LR, but you are much more likely to have an Uzi that can fire 9 mm or 45-ACP. It is certainly plausible that none of your SMGs will fire a 22 LR round - again the most common round.